# ¿Cómo mostrar datos en un TextBox?

Tags: json, vb.net, visual-studio

Tengo un problema, tengo una aplicación en **Vb.net** que **deserealiza** un Archivo **.json** así:

```
{
    "Personal": [
        {
            "nombre": "Martin",
            "apellido": "Scarpini"
            "correo": "martin.scar2130@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Angel",
            "apellido": "Velazquez",
            "correo": "angel3001.velazquz@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Jose",
            "apellido": "Perez",
            "correo": "perezjose2@hotmail.com"
        },

    ]
}
```

Y quiero mostrar los datos de **nombre**, **apellido** y **correo** en un **TextBox** pero no encuentro la forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el código que use para **deserealizar** el archivo **.json**

```
Public Class PersonalContainer
        Public Property Personal As List(Of PersonaViewModel)
    End Class

    Public Class Personal
        Public Property nombre As String
        Public Property apellido As String
        Public Property correo As String
    End Class

Dim viewModel As PersonalViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of PersonalContainer)(json)
```

Una de las cosas que intenté fue almacenar los datos en variables y después mostrarlos en las cajas de texto, pero no lo logré.

Comment: Cuando deseralizas el json el mismo contiene una lista de personas, que vas hacer con esa lista de personas?, por que en tu form solo colocas 3 texbox que solo alcanza para los datos de una persona. O solo necesitas mostrar en los texbox cualquiera de los 3?

Comment: Quiero, mostrar en los 3 textbox los datos de la primera persona, luego en formulario habrán 2 botones que dicen "Siguiete" y "Limpiar". el boton limpiar, limpiara los 3 textbox y  boton Siguiente limpiara los textbox y mostrara los datos de la siguiente persona en la lista.